# How to add active class using jQuery with Backbone.js library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I am trying to add an active class on `a` tag using jQuery with Backbone.js library...I've done something but nothing happens when I click that tag.

HTML:

```
<div class="bets_view">
  <div class="filtering_options">
    <a href="#brzn/yolo/all" class="btn btn-filter">All</a>
    <a href="#brzn/yolo/open" class="btn btn-filter">Open</a>
    <a href="#brzn/yolo/closed" class="btn btn-filter">Closed</a>
    <a href="#brzn/yolo/ended" class="btn btn-filter">Ended</a>
    <a href="#brzn/yolo/resolved" class="btn btn-filter">Resolved</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
  events:
    "click a.btn-filter": "activeTab"

  activeTab: (e)->
    $el.removeClass("active-tab")
    $(this).addClass("active-tab")
```

Comment: You use wrong approach. `activeTab` handler shouldn't do any change in DOM. It should change **model's state**, which should be reflected by your View's `render`

Comment: Can you be more explicit on this, please? What should I change in my code?

Comment: I'll be more explicit once you provide more details. I guess that's not your full JS code.

Comment: There is a lot of JS code according to interactions on the page, but I assume that the `active` class can be added with a click event

Comment: _I assume that the active class can be added with a click event._ Sure, it can be. But this is the jquery approach. If you use Backbone, it's better to use [its approach](http://backbonejs.org/#Getting-started) instead. Otherwise Backbone is useless.

Comment: It would be no problem if I can fix this using jQuery, in fact it would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Backbone `this` refers to the current view, and not the element that triggered the event.

You can get the element from the `e` object: (*CoffeeScript syntax*)

```
activeTab: (e)->
    elem = e.currentTarget
    $elem = $(e.currentTarget)

    ## Remove .active class from previous item
    $('.filtering_options a.active').removeClass('active-tab')

    ## Set .active class to clicked item
    $elem.addClass("active-tab")
```